# webservices connection using axis2 and apache

Tags: java, web-services, axis

i wish to connecting webservices in java using apache,axis2 and eclipse.

here i got following error:

```
[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method customerData
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: namespace mismatch require http://ws.retailer.com found http://ws.retailer.com/
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:190)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

How is cleared these error.please guide me.

Comment: thanks for editing the question Jigar Joshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: namespace mismatch require http://ws.retailer.com found http://ws.retailer.com/
```

One URL has a trailing backslash, the other doesn't.

You can configure your server.  Here's the documentation for "Apache re-writes":

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

Easier, just make sure your endpoint exactly matches the URL.